# Notificação com alarm manager

Tags: android, android-notification, android-alarmmanager

Um dos objectivos finais da minha  aplicação é enviar notificações ao utilizador em uma certa hora . O meu alarm manager está a funcionar correctamente agora o meu problema é são as notificações que não são mostradas.

O objectivo é mostrar uma notificação passados 10 segundos mas não estou a receber qualquer tipo de notificação.

**O meu código de enviar notificações:**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificationManager mNM;
    mNM = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Teste",
            System.currentTimeMillis());

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "TESTE" , "Teste", contentIntent);

    mNM.notify(0, notification);
}
```

}

**Chamo o receiver pelo meu alarm manager :**

```
 PendingIntent alarmIntent;


            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
            alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
            long firstTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();


            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstTime, alarmIntent);
```

**Adicionei no meu AndroidManifest.xml** :

```
<receiver android:process=":remote" android:name="AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
```

Comment: Você deixou `}` fora da formatação Tiago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está a criar o PendingIntent de forma errada.
[PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) é um mecanismo que o Android utiliza para permitir uma aplicação externa(NotificationManager, AlarmManager e outros) usar as permissões do seu aplicativo para executar um código pré-definido.

Ele disponibiliza diversos métodos estáticos a serem usados de acordo com o tipo de código a executar.

Neste caso, como quer executar um BradcastReceiver, deverá usar o método [PendingIntent.getBroadcast()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)) e não [PendingIntent.getActivity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)) que deve ser utilizado quando quer lançar uma Activity.

Substitua a linha

```
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
```

por

```
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.Broadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
```